# Using "just" with Present Perfect Continuos

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

We can say:

> 1. We have already made the decision.
> 2. We have already been learning English for a half of a year.

Thus, I may use "just" either with Present Perfect/Past Perfect and Present Perfect Continuos/Past Perfect Continuos? For instance:

> 1. We have just talked about you.
> 2. We have just been talking about you.

Futher to the above, is it necessary use "just" with Present Perfect Continuos or it is obviously that the actions is going on at the moment of saying this remark?

Comment: "just" there is deictic, and means "quite recently" or "only a little time ago".  Whether  "quite recently" or "a little time ago" means a moment ago or in the past few days or even in the past few weeks is in the speaker's mind.  The present perfect continuous implies some sort of recency as well; **just** therefore has merely an emphatic force, and is not necessary to the meaning, as the meaning is imprecise in any case.

Comment: It's true that we have been talking about him. But not today.